# GC limit exceeded with few data

Tags: neo4j

i have a graph with 20000 nodes. The following code raise an exception.

```
    double Di=0;
    Iterator<Relationship> rel;
    int cnt=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < geni.size(); i++) 
        { 
          Di=0;
          cnt=0;
          rel = geni.get(i).getRelationships(RelTypes.SIM).iterator();    
          while (rel.hasNext())
              {Di+=(Double)rel.next().getProperty("SIM");   
              cnt++;
              }
          System.out.println(i+" "+cnt);
                      }
```

This code print:

```
0 11749
1 11974
2 11949
.
.
74 10126
75 10102
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

if i use:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
long freeMem = r.freeMemory();
System.out.println("free memory: " + freeMem);
```

i can see a lot of free memory.

i have one istance of Di, one istance of cnt, one istance of rel. I dont understand why i have this exception.

Comment: Could you please show us your JVM settings?

Comment: are you executing this over REST or embedded db?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: And what is your Neo4j version?

Answer (score 0):

Try committing your transaction every couple of thousand operations, i.e:

Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
try
{
    for ( int i = 0; i

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced my graph (5k nodes, 2,5m edges).
Each node have the same number of edges.
With this code:

```
    Iterator<Relationship> rel;
    int i=0;
    for ( Node n : Neo4Jstore.geneIndex.query( "gene", "**" ) )
        { System.out.println(++i);
          rel = n.getRelationships(RelTypes.SIM).iterator();             
          while (rel.hasNext())
              rel.next();   
        }
```

the execution end in 37s, it's high but ok

if i change the code with this:

```
    Iterator<Relationship> rel;
    int i=0;
    for ( Node n : Neo4Jstore.geneIndex.query( "gene", "**" ) )
        { System.out.println(++i);
          rel = n.getRelationships(RelTypes.SIM).iterator();             
          while (rel.hasNext())
              rel.next().getProperty("SIM");    
        }
```

the execution end in 4 minutes! i can see into the console that the iteration "i" take a larger amount of time than "i-1". Why? It's normal?

Comment: Because you load about 10k relationship properties per iteration from disk? What is the runtime for the second round? You also might want to check your JVM heap and Neo4j cache settings.